# How to edit meta tags in DotNetNuke

Tags: html, dotnetnuke, meta-tags, w3c-validation

how do you edit tags in the DotNetNuke CMS?

it generates lots of meta tags and has an ID element for each meta tag which is not in the w3c recommendations. Ive looked at SEO optimization articles and it says not to have any other meta tags other than for the keywords and name -- is this true?

Meta tags when i view the source code:

```
<meta id="MetaKeywords" name="KEYWORDS" content="naruto, fan, forums, DotNetNuke,DNN" />
<meta id="MetaCopyright" name="COPYRIGHT" content="Copyright naruto"/>
<meta id="MetaGenerator" name="GENERATOR" content="DotNetNuke " />
<meta id="MetaAuthor" name="AUTHOR" content="naruto" />
<meta name="RESOURCE-TYPE" content="DOCUMENT" />
<meta name="DISTRIBUTION" content="GLOBAL" />
<meta name="REVISIT-AFTER" content="1 DAYS" />
```

Comment: This looks like a bunch of questions rolled into one. Which one do you want answered? Warning: choose carefully, since not all questions below on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there is not a straightforward/supported way to remove most of those `meta` tags in DNN.  You'll need to do some degree of altering the core code and/or making assumptions that certain IDs will stay the same.  For example, you can remove/replace with robots meta tag by putting [code like this](https://gist.github.com/2783797) in the skin:

```
private void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var metaRobots = Page.FindControl("MetaRobots") as HtmlMeta;
    if (metaRobots != null) {
        metaRobots.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can delete them from Default.aspx using any text editor, however this can prove troublesome as you'll probably rewrite it with next update, so I'd recommend you append this simple C# snippet to the bottom of your skin .ascx file

```
<script runat="server">
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    var metatagsToKeep = new[] { "Content-Type", "Content-Script-Type", "Content-Style-Type", "Refresh", "DESCRIPTION", "KEYWORDS", "COPYRIGHT", "GENERATOR", "AUTHOR", "RESOURCE-TYPE", "DISTRIBUTION", "ROBOTS", "REVISIT-AFTER", "RATING", "PAGE-ENTER" };

    var metaTags = (from headerControl in this.Page.Header.Controls.OfType<HtmlControl>() let cont = headerControl where !metatagsToKeep.Contains(cont.Attributes["name"]) && !metatagsToKeep.Contains(cont.Attributes["http-equiv"]) select headerControl).Cast<Control>().ToList();

    foreach (var metaTag in metaTags)
    {
        this.Page.Header.Controls.Remove(metaTag);
    } 
}
</script>
```

In the controlsToKeep array just remove ones you want to remove and you are done. In case DNN adds some new you'd want (which is unlikely), you'll have to add them to the list. Or you can reverse logic and create array for metatagsToDelete, your call :).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer for the first part of the question applying specifically to `dotnetnuke CMS`, I do however have some comments to assist you in the question regarding `SEO`.

In general meta tags will not hurt you in search engine optimization.  Google does not use the keywords tag in it's ranking algorithm, other search engines that do recognize it may hurt your ranking if your keywords do not have significant density for the page.

### Search Engine Optimization

`SEO` is often recognized as a collective of good practices for rankings.  To the contrary, each search engine has it's own unique algorithm.  To truly have good `SEO` you need to focus on a specific area that you would like to improve results and optimize accordingly.

### Meta Tags

Meta tags are metadata for your web page, not necessarily the entire site.  The information contained within them should assist applications and services in processing the information on that page.  This tag is a general property that isn't necessarily recognized by anything.  There is no central authority over what is and is not a valid meta tag because it is a generic purpose element.

Meta tags should simply be disregarded by any application or service that does not recognize them.

*From the W3C recommendations:*

> Note. The META element is a generic mechanism for specifying meta data. However, some HTML elements and attributes already handle certain pieces of meta data and may be used by authors instead of META to specify those pieces: the TITLE element, the ADDRESS element, the INS and DEL elements, the title attribute, and the cite attribute

There is a specification as far as the proper syntax of a meta element.  The `name`, `scheme`, `content`, and `http-equiv` attributes are defined for the meta tag by the W3C.  The `lang` and `dir` attributes are also defined as properties for a meta element that are inherited by parent attributes, but can be overridden at the element level.

The `id` attribute is not specified for the meta element and should cause validation failure.

Answer (score 0):

In DotNetNuke, the keyword and description tags come from two places. 
1.) In Admin -> Site Settings in the Site Details section, you'll see entries for Keywords and Description which are used to populate the corresponding meta tags for all pages. We recommend you leave both of these fields blank as you don't want redundant entries for multiple pages.
2.) Page Settings: for each page you can specify the keywords and description through the page settings. Keywords are ignored by the major search engines so we recommend leaving that blank as well. The description however is what will generally show up on the search results page and so is very important.

As for the other meta tags generated, I haven't heard that they have much of an impact. I recommend just letting them be.